# Nodejs server not responding to Axios post from an HTTPS website

Tags: node.js, reactjs, ssl

I have created a nodejs/express server (on a hosted cloud server service) to process and serve back to a reactjs website (hosted at a different service) processed information. It worked on http on localhost and even running http in the current configuration. I started getting the following error when I made the website secure with SSL - "net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR".

The website is running on an APACHE webserver, while the nodejs/express server is running on a Linux/Ubuntu platform.

I have tried self certifying with openssl, but it fails with an error indicating the certificate is self generated.

Users don't access nodejs server directly, and the only access to the server is through the website.

Am I better off trying to tie the self generated SSL certificate on the nodejs server to the website axios calls? Will that bypass the SSL errors? Will it introduce other issues I need to be aware of?

Thanks in advance for your help.

If there are existing stackoverflow issues addressing my question, please point me in the direction.

Comment: Alternatively, would it help if I were to run the webserver and the nodejs server on the same cloud server?

Comment: Instead of a full fledged answer, just a hint here:  regarding your error on self-certifying: Maybe you could checkout https://letsencrypt.org/getting-started/
The ReactJS website (on Apache webserver) behaves just like a browser in this case. So, it should not be necessary to do anything there (apart from mentioning the HTTPS protocol in the API-Calls to NodeJS). Setting up the SSL certificate on the NodeJS size should be enough.

Comment: Please edit the title of your question to tell us more specifically what your question is about, not to tell us how you've searched for an answer.  You can read [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more info about a good title and other aspects of a good question.

Comment: If using a self-signed certificate, the client (which is probably the browser in this case) has to be taught to trust that self-signed certificate otherwise it will fail with the SSL connection establishment.  It is probably better to get a free real certificate from letsencrypt.

Answer (score 0):

I've added a CA issued SSL and I've been able to get by the initial problem of not connecting at all. I then configured CORS, and I'm able to get through to the server using Postman, but it still fails off the website. I'm going to open a new question with this specific information. Thank you all for your helpl